# Looking for architecture documentations of open source applications (no lib/framework/os) for learning purpose

Tags: user-interface, architecture, documentation

I am studying how open source applications (projects that come with UI) document their architectures.

Can someone suggest any links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I would start my investigation on github with the following searches:

```
https://github.com/search?q=architecture+language%3AMarkdown+%60%60%60plantuml&type=code
```

or

```
https://github.com/search?q=architecture+language%3AMarkdown+%60%60%60mermaid&type=code
```

Basically these queries look for

- the keyword `Architecture`
- in markdown files
- where there is a [plantuml](https://plantuml.com/) or a [mermaid](https://mermaid.js.org/) diagram